# Run cronjob with browser request

Tags: wp-cron

Open the wp-cron.php page into the browser, eg. opening this url
http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron run the cronjob or WordPress block request made by browser?

Comment: It will run any cron jobs that are scheduled to run. It's a common practice to create a real cron job on the server that hits this URL, if that's what you're looking to do.

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better off using the wordpress API:

```
function wp_register_cron_endpoint() {
  register_rest_route( 'crons', '/run_cron', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' =>  'run_crons'
  )); 
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_register_cron_endpoint' );

function run_crons(){
  /*** Do whatever you want ***/
}
```

Then you can hit http://example.com/crons/run_crons and you'll A)Trigger wp_cron based on the wp_load and B) Do whatever you want in the function.